# How to insert pictures in org-mode for Beamer export?

Tags: beamer, org-mode, export

I'm writing a presentation with Org-mode + beamer. I'm trying to include a picture but when exporting to 'PDF (Beamer)' with `C-c C-e l P` combo, the pdf isn't produced. I get this error msg: "org-latex-compile: PDF file ./ppt.pdf wasn't produced: Runaway argument".
Also, if I click on the image link with the mouse I get: "Type C-c C-c to view the image as an image.
Cannot display image: (Cannot determine image type)"

This is a **MWE** for `ppt.org`. Can you help me spot the mistake and correct it?

```
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation, smaller]
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+BEAMER_THEME: CambridgeUS
#+BEAMER_FONT_THEME: structurebold
#+BEAMER_ENV:
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col) %8BEAMER_OPT(Opt)
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t email:n |:t
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \frenchspacing
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \graphicspath{{./IMGs/}}
#+TITLE: presentation
#+AUTHOR:
#+DATE: Dec 2015


* Intro
** What are CNTs?
*** when? who?                            :BMCOL:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: block
    :BEAMER_col: 0.57
    :END:
- 1952 bla bla bla
- 1991 Dr. Sumio Iijima publishes ``Helical microtubules of graphitic carbon'' 
*** second column                     :B_ignoreheading:BMCOL:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
    :BEAMER_col: 0.24
    :END:
    #+ATTR_LATEX: width=\textwidth
    [[./IMGs/sumioIjima.jpg]]
```

Comment: If I investigate the .tex file and compile that with pdflatex I get "ERROR: File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.". This is strange because yesterday, one of the compilations went well and I was able to open the pdf and see the picture that I'm trying to include.

Comment: I managed to root out the error -- a couple of environments in the .tex file weren't closed properly. Also when the tex file is generated, `[[file.jpg]]` is not automatically inserted into a `figure` environment. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your code I have trouble with the `ignoreheading` option. A way to solve this is to write:

```
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation, smaller]
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+BEAMER_THEME: CambridgeUS
#+BEAMER_FONT_THEME: structurebold
#+BEAMER_ENV:
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col) %8BEAMER_OPT(Opt)
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t email:n |:t
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \frenchspacing
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \graphicspath{{./IMGs/}}
#+TITLE: presentation
#+AUTHOR:
#+DATE: Dec 2015


* Intro
** What are CNTs?
*** when? who?                                :BMCOL:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: block
    :BEAMER_col: 0.6
    :END:
- 1952 bla bla bla
- 1991 Dr. Sumio Iijima publishes ``Helical microtubules of graphitic carbon'' 
*** second column                       :B_ignoreheading:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: block
    :BEAMER_col: 0.4
    :END:      
    #+ATTR_LATEX: width=\textwidth
    [[./tmp.jpg]]
```

So you avoid using `:BEAMER_env: ignoreheading` and have as output:

[image]